# SSL TurnKey Linux

Tags: linux, ssl

I have a TurnKey Mantis linux appliance and I want to make the connection secure.I've bought from GlobeHost a certificate and got the following files :sub-domain_domain_net.ca-bundle and sub-domain_domain_net.crt.I've got the Sftp connection to work.How can I install the certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post, should answer you question.

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/ssl-certificates